# Google plus get Comments with PHP Code

Tags: php, json, feed, google-plus

I would like to read my Google Plus Feed with an php site and list all entrys in an array.... Now I found the explanation site of Google

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list

But I dont understand what I have to do?!? Can anybody give me a hint or an example, how to read my own newfeed from google + with an php coded site?

thank you in advance

regards Dennis

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it is better you to use the [google-api-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) which has methods to easily access content on Google Plus from PHP.

Comment: yeah that should help... thank you.. thats what i was looking for... if somebody got some ready code to share, it would be helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out the [Google+ PHP Starter Project](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-php-starter/), which provides some configure and run code. One of the features demonstrated by this starter project is a list of your public activities.